# Obtener el tema de Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp

Buenos días.

Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de obtener en C# si el sistema está en modo/tema oscuro o claro y hacer el requested theme de la app sea el mismo.

La configuración del tema en Windows es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, si tengo un grid de fondo, cuando el ordenador esté configurado en modo oscuro, que ese grid se vuelva de color negro. Se que poniendo lo siguiente se consigue el color de énfasis:

```
Grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Resources["SystemAccentColor"]);
```

Pero lo que necesito es el tema claro o oscuro definido por el usuario en la configuración de Windows.

Gracias por todo!

Comment: Por favor revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que te podamos ayudar mejor. Las preguntas deben reflejar cierto grado de esfuerzo previo

Comment: Aclara a que llamas thema oscuro o claro. nunca escuche de eso.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solucón funciona a partir del Aniversary Update

Anda al archivo `App.xaml` y quítale la sgte línea:

```
<Application
    ...
    RequestedTheme="Light">
</Application>
```

Luego es esto puedes acceder al tema de Windows mediante:

```
Application.Current.RequestedTheme
```

Sin embargo tal vez ya no sea necesario averiguar el tema actual ya que la app utilizará también el tema de Windows.

Si no quitas la línea del `App.xaml` el `ApplicationTheme` devuelto por la llamada al método anterior será siempre el que esté definido en el `App.xaml`